# Code to produce a sequence with repeating pattern

Tags: python, sequence

I need a code that does the following sequence giving the number x :

- x=1 : 1,3,5,7
- x=2 : 1,3,5,7,5,7,9,11,13
- x=3 : 1,3,5,7,5,7,9,11,13,11,13,15,17,19,21
- x=4 : 1,3,5,7,5,7,9,11,13,11,13,15,17,19,21,19,21,23,25,27,29
- x=5 : 1,3,5,7,5,7,9,11,13,11,13,15,17,19,21,19,21,23,25,27,29,27,29,31,33,35,37,39
  I'm having issue on the part where pattern repeats itself from the old one before continuing the +2 thing.
  Here's my code that does the +2 thing in an odd way since I've been trying to do the repeat thing :

```py
def sequence(number):
    result = 1
    minus = 2
    for i in range(1,number+1):
        for j in range(1, i+4):
            print(result)
            result += 2
        if i%2==0:
            minus += 1
            result -= minus
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just explicitly reduce the result at the end of the outer loop?

```
def sequence(number):
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, number+1):
        for j in range(1, i+4):
            print(result, end=' ')
            result += 2
        result -= 4
    print()
```

That results in the following if you call it with numbers 1 though 5. That is, however, assuming you want to enhance the sequence by one item more in each iteration. Your code suggests that, but the example is different in the latter two cases. If the example is correct you would have to keep the i range constant from the third step on.

```
1 3 5 7 
1 3 5 7 5 7 9 11 13 
1 3 5 7 5 7 9 11 13 11 13 15 17 19 21 
1 3 5 7 5 7 9 11 13 11 13 15 17 19 21 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 
1 3 5 7 5 7 9 11 13 11 13 15 17 19 21 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43
```

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for but too much coding today I couldn't think of this, thank you so much!